# Issue when looping through form fields in Django's __init__ method

Tags: django

My goal is to loop through all form fields and to assign certain classes to them like this:

```
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):    
        super(ContactForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)   
        for field_name, field in self.fields.items():
            field.widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control input-sm plain'
            if field.required == True: 
                field.widget.attrs['required'] = ''

    class Meta:
        model = Contact
        fields = '__all__'
```

The issue with this code is that `self.fields.items()` seems to be empty (and as a result I never get into the for-loop).

My guess is that the issue arose either because of my upgrade from Django 1.9 and python 2 to Django 1.10 and python 3, or because of custom manager present in the definition of the underlying model.

Could anyone share expertise on this?

```
class Contact(BaseMixin, DeleteMixin):
    provider_account = models.ForeignKey(ProviderAccount, models.DO_NOTHING)
    client_id = models.IntegerField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    profile_photo_url = models.CharField(max_length=100, default = 'no_image.jpg')
    event_type_id = models.IntegerField(EventType.choices(), blank=True, null=True)
    is_satisfied = models.NullBooleanField()
    objects = CustomQuerySetManager()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'contact'

    class QuerySet(QuerySet):
        #....
```

Comment: Instead you can try this : https://github.com/kmike/django-widget-tweaks

Comment: Could you please provide a full form? It is hard to find the issue form current code. By some reason fields are not collected by the metaclass: https://github.com/django/django/blob/3c447b108ac70757001171f7a4791f493880bf5b/django/forms/forms.py#L45

Comment: That's the entire form. Should I provide the model ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form is a standard form, not a model form; the Meta class is ignored and the only fields are those you define yourself.

Your form should inherit from `forms.ModelForm` for this to work.